# Error with inserting a point into a geometry (point) typed column in Postgress with PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgis, pydantic, geoalchemy2

I need to insert a point into `Column(Geometry(geometry_type='POINT', srid=4326))`. I can not figure out how to implement the `srid=4326` into the point data `POINT(58.183594 22.593726)`. I searched for it. I still cannot solve this!

Error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidParameterValue) Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (4326)

[SQL: INSERT INTO addresses (label, coordinates, building_number, flat_number, disabled, created_at, updated_at, user_id) VALUES (%(label)s, ST_GeomFromEWKT(%(coordinates)s), %(building_number)s, %(flat_number)s, %(disabled)s, %(created_at)s, %(updated_at)s, %(user_id)s) RETURNING addresses.id]
[parameters: {'label': 'my home', 'coordinates': 'POINT(58.183594 22.593726)', 'building_number': 1, 'flat_number': None, 'disabled': False, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 28, 11, 11, 3, 913693), 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 28, 11, 11, 3, 913706), 'user_id': 1}]
```

FastAPI route:

```
@router.post("/{id}/addresses", response_model=schemas.AddressOut)
async def create_a_new_address(id:int, address_in: schemas.AddressIn, db: Session = Depends(get_db), token_data: schemas.TokenDecoded = Depends(auth.decode_token)):
    if id == token_data.id or auth.can_access(token_data.bitrole, "USERS"):
        address_in_db= schemas.AddressInDB(**address_in.dict(), user_id=id)
        return crud.create_address(db=db, address=address_in_db)
    else:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="access denied"
        )
```

pydantic (schemas.py):

```
def set_now(time: datetime.datetime)-> datetime.datetime:
    return time or datetime.datetime.now()

def tuple_to_point(coord_tuple: Tuple)->str:
    return f'POINT({coord_tuple[0]} {coord_tuple[1]})'

class AddressIn(BaseModel):
    label:                 str = ...
    coordinates:           Tuple[float,float] = ...
    building_number:       int = ...
    flat_number:           Optional[int]=None

class AddressInDB(AddressIn):
    created_at:            datetime.datetime = None
    updated_at:            datetime.datetime = None
    coordinates:           str = ...
    user_id:               int = ...
    _created_at = validator('created_at', allow_reuse=True, pre=True, always=True)(set_now)
    _updated_at = validator('updated_at', allow_reuse=True, pre=True, always=True)(set_now)   
    _coordinates = validator('coordinates', allow_reuse=True, pre=True, always=True)(tuple_to_point)

class AddressOut(AddressInDB):
    id:                    int
```

sqlalchemy,geoalchemy2 (tables.py):

```
class Addresses(Base):
    __tablename__="addresses"

    id=                   Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    label=                Column(String)
    coordinates=          Column(Geometry(geometry_type='POINT', srid=4326))
    building_number=      Column(String)
    flat_number=          Column(String, nullable=True)
    disabled =            Column(Boolean, default=False)
    created_at=           Column(DateTime)
    updated_at=           Column(DateTime)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

crud.py

```
def create_address(db: Session, address: schemas.AddressInDB):
    db_address = tables.Addresses(**address.dict())
    db.add(db_address)

    try:
        db.commit()
    except IntegrityError as e:
        process_db_error(e)

    db.refresh(db_address)
    return db_address
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the EWKT representation:

```
'SRID=4326;POINT(58.183594 22.593726)'
```